# Disable resize gizmo of area light in viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, light, lighting, gizmo

Every time I try to transform an area light I end up clicking on the edge of the light icon and resizing it. This is really messing with my workflow. Is there a way to disable this behavior? I want to control the light size through the parameters only.

How can I disable area light resize gizmo in the viewport?

Answer (score 1):

You can either disable the ['Size'](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/gizmo.html#light) gizmo under *3D View > Viewport Gizmos > Lights* **or** just *turn off* all [Viewport Gizmos](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/gizmo.html#viewport-gizmos) temporarily by using the [Show Gizmo](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/gizmo.html#viewport-gizmos) switch (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>) in the header of the 3D View:

[image]

Comment: Alternatively I recommend try to get used to `g` and `r` hotkeys to transform the light, it's just faster. In terms of workflow, I can also recommend to transform the light from the lights perspective by temporarily making it the actual viewport camera (`Ctrl+Numpad 0`).

Comment: I am not sure what is going on here. I answered my own question yesterday. Did you edit my answer? Where did it go? So bizarre.

Anyway, thanks, I had figured it out already. The G and R hotkeys are not going to work for me. I find transforming things without a cursor to be very non-intuitive. This is one of my least favorite things about Blender. Constantly being dumped into a mode where there's no cursor on the screen, but the mouse controls the position of something until the user makes a click. Like make a duplicate, create a shading node, etc. It really is poor design.

Comment: So yeah, it looks like you trampled over my answer? What kind of power trip is this? You can't just leave it alone? It's helpful to expand upon an answer, but it is extremely bad etiquette to delete. This is why I stopped contributing to Wikipedia, people are egomaniac jerks.

Comment: I just "suggested an edit" to improve your (low-quality) answer to help out future visitors, you can always roll it back: https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/234128/revisions. Consider that this no regular forum. We do that all day btw, you're welcome.

Comment: My answer gave the essential information. I'm sorry that I don't have all day to contribute to this place, I actually have a job and a life. But I must reiterate that expanding on an answer is helpful. Just blasting over the top of it is offensive. You can do that all day if you want, but that doesn't make it right.

Comment: I don't get your attitude, what's so "bad" on having a complete explanation and an image to support that? See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer